# How to save markers position to localStorage in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, leaflet, markers

I am trying new to localStorage, and I am trying to save the markers that the user can create on the map.

I created this function to place markers and delete them:

```
var redmarker = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/paomedia/small-n-flat/48/map-marker-icon.png',

       iconSize:     [48, 48], // size of the icon
       iconAnchor:   [24, 48], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
       popupAnchor:  [-2, -48] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                        });

        var popup = L.popup();

        // On map click shows coordinates X, Y
        function onMapClick(e) {

          var geojsonFeature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]
            }
          }

          var marker;

          L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

            pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng){

              marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {

                title: "Resource Location",
                alt: "Resource Location",
                riseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                icon: redmarker


              }).bindPopup("<<span>X: " + e.latlng.lng + ", Y: " + e.latlng.lat + "</span><br><a href='#' id='marker-delete-button'>Delete marker</a>");

              marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

              return marker;
            }
          }).addTo(map);
        }

        function onPopupOpen() {
          var tempMarker = this;

          $("#marker-delete-button:visible").click(function () {
            map.removeLayer(tempMarker);
          });
        }

        map.on('click', onMapClick);
```

I am not familiar with localStorage, this is new to me. Also I am trying to make the popup editable, an user input there for the user name the marker.
I saw this example of input:

http://tahvel.info/simpleStorage/example/

Something like that.

A working example of my function: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2g4h5eu5/1/

Can someone help  me save the markers in localStorage?
Also my problem is that I don't know what render's the markers on leaflet after I click, so I don't know exactly what I need to save in local storage to retrieve those markers.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following functions to manage your localStorage

`localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','vanilla');`

`var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
// -> "vanilla"`

`localStorage.removeItem('favoriteflavor');
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
// -> null`

check this [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)
also you can use [jQuery Storage API](https://plugins.jquery.com/storageapi/) plugin to make things more cross-browser

http://fiddle.jshell.net/thesane/2g4h5eu5/29/

```
/// Load markers
function loadMarkers()
{
    var markers = localStorage.getItem("markers");
  if(!markers) return;
  markers = JSON.parse(markers);
  markers.forEach(function(entry) {
    latlng = JSON.parse(entry);
    var geojsonFeature = {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {},
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [latlng.lat, latlng.lng]
                        }
                    }

                    var marker;

                    L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {

                        pointToLayer: function(feature){

                            marker = L.marker(latlng, {

                                title: "Resource Location",
                                alt: "Resource Location",
                                riseOnHover: true,
                                draggable: true,
                icon: redmarker


                            }).bindPopup("<<span>X: " + latlng.lng + ", Y: " + latlng.lat + "</span><br><a href='#' id='marker-delete-button'>Delete marker</a>");

                            marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);

                            return marker;
                        }
                    }).addTo(map);
});
}
/// Store markers
function storeMarker(marker)
{
    var markers = localStorage.getItem("markers");
  if(!markers) {
    markers = new Array();
    console.log(marker);
    markers.push(JSON.stringify(marker));
  }
  else
  {
    markers = JSON.parse(markers);
    markers.push(JSON.stringify(marker));
  }
   console.log(JSON.stringify(markers));
  localStorage.setItem('markers', JSON.stringify(markers));
}

// Delete Marker
function deleteMarker(lng, lat) {
  var markers = localStorage.getItem("markers");
  markers = JSON.parse(markers);
   for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
    latlng = JSON.parse(markers[i]);

    if(latlng.lat == lat && latlng.lng == lng)
    {
        markers.splice(i,1);

    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem('markers', JSON.stringify(markers));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also my problem is what objects I need to save to the localStorage to retrieve the markers later, since I can add more than one marker.

Comment: Very nice! And how I can make the delete button remove the current marker from the localStorage and not all markers?

Comment: make the delete button call a function with (lat, lng) parameters, then use the same method in storeMaker to retrieve the markers list and search for the matching lat/lng values, remove it from the array then write it back to storage

Comment: I know I am asking a lot, but could you point me on how to write that function? I am not that good with javascript! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: if you don't try yourself first you will never get better in it. use my previous comment as  a guide and make something out of it and I will be more than happy to help out after that.

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I don't know how to write javascript like you said. I still learning the basics. I didn't understand the part where you said to use the same method in storeMarker to retrieve the markers. I didn't understand how the latlng parameters are being stored for me to retrieve. I am trying here.

Comment: After trying pretty much everything I doubt this can be done. Because deleting one marker its much harder than I think. When I add the marker to the map, I add the marker to the layer too, so if I want to delete just one marker, I will have to delete it from the layer too. That's when the things get complicated. I don't know if it can be done...